# Mixed Moments of Hypercontractive Distributions

Tags: probability

Suppose we have a distribution $\mathcal{D}$ over $\mathbb{R}^d$ with mean $μ = 0$ and covariance $Σ = Ι$ such that, given $X = \left(X_1, \dots, X_d\right) \sim \mathcal{D}$ the moment bound $\mathbb{E} \left[ \left( v^{\top} X \right)^4 \right] \le C \mathbb{E}\left[ \left( v^{\top} X \right)^2 \right]^2, \forall v \in \mathbb{R}^d$ is satisfied. When dealing with mixed moments of the form $\mathbb{E} \left[ X_i^2 X_j^2 \right]$, is there a better upper bound than $C$, which is what is produced using Cauchy-Schwarz and the moment assumption? Using only these tools essentially ignores the fact that the non-diagonal elements of $Σ$ are $0$. However, given that this is not a Gaussian, uncorrelatedness does not imply independence so we can't write $\mathbb{E} \left[ X_i^2 X_j^2 \right] = \mathbb{E} \left[ X_i^2 \right] \mathbb{E} \left[ X_j^2 \right] = 1$. Is there any other intelligent way to reason about this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can do much better than this in general.

---

Take $X$ that is $2^{n/2}$ with probability $2^{-n}$ and 0 with probability $1-2^{-n}$. From this, we can construct an uncorrelated pair $(X,\varepsilon X)$, with $\varepsilon$ being an independent random sign. You can check that the covariance matrix is the identity, and for any $\alpha^2+\beta^2=1$,
\begin{align*}
\mathsf E\left(\alpha X+\beta\varepsilon X\right)^4&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\mathsf E\left(\alpha X+\beta X\right)^4+\mathsf E\left(\alpha X-\beta X\right)^4\right)\\
&\le 2^{n-1}\left(\left(\mathsf E\left(\alpha X+\beta X\right)^2\right)^2+\left(\mathsf E\left(\alpha X-\beta X\right)^2\right)^2\right)\\
&\le 2^{n-1}\left(\mathsf E\left(\alpha X+\beta X\right)^2+\mathsf E\left(\alpha X-\beta X\right)^2\right)^2\\
&=2^{n+1}\left(\mathsf E\left(\alpha X+\beta \varepsilon X\right)^2\right)^2.
\end{align*}
whereas, of course
$$
\mathsf E X^2(\varepsilon X)^2=\mathsf E X^4=2^n.
$$
So the bound of $C$ is tight, at least up to this constant 2.